# Move Android layout's background

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a big image which I have set as background to my android layout and I would like to move it (either from left to right, right to left, doesn't matter)
I would normally use an animated image, but Android doesn't natively support apng or gif, so is it possible to move the background instead?
I have added 2 pictures to make myself more clear.

[image: The image is moving slowly]

[image: The real image size]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by move the image?

Comment: Are you saying you want the background image to scroll from side to side continuously while the app is running?

Comment: @William Brendel Excatly this is what I'm thing of.

Answer (score 0):

i think what you are looking for is some way of implementation of the [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) read a little bit about it, it might be your solution.

Comment: I can't use Gallery, because it has to be the background of a layout.

Comment: well, the only thing i can think of, is you handling the drawable on a back thread with an endless loop, you set the speed of your loop, you create a Runnable that changes the background, and you call runOnUiThread(yourRunnable);

You gotta do all the work for changing the background on your Runnable.